# Haskell Queue as an instance for Show

Tags: haskell

I have written a Queue Datatype in Haskell data Queue = .....

And now we have been asked to define a function showQueue as a helper function to declare my data Queue as an instance from Show (prelude)

Really do not know how to do this.

Could anyone help me, please ?

Thanks in anticipation !

PS: If necessary , I can post my code of data Queue.

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
        data Queue a = Q [a]
                        deriving Show

      isEmpty :: Queue a -> Bool
      isEmpty (Q []) = True
      isEmpty (Q _) = False

       enqueue :: (Ord a) => a -> Queue a -> Queue a
       enqueue x (Q xs) = Q (xs++[x])
```

Comment: Post code for data Queue.

Comment: Are you meant to format the output in a specific way? Your `Queue` type already is already deriving `Show`, so are you meant to remove that and create an explicit instance?

Comment: Hello, no I am asked to add an EXTRA function as a helper function to make Queue as an instance from show. deriving Show must not be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you need to write your own instance of `Show` instead of using `deriving`. You probably need to display each of the elements in the queue. In this case, the element type `a` needs to be an instance of `Show`, then you can combine the displayed values together in some way e.g.

```
instance Show a => Show (Queue a) where
    show (Q l) = "Queue " ++ show l
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be one of the way to solve this problem:

```
data Queue a = Q [a]

instance Show a => Show (Queue a) where
  show = showQueue

showQueue :: Show a => Queue a -> String
showQueue (Q xs) = concat $ intersperse "," $ map show xs
```

showQueue is a function demonstrating sample output. You can show custom output in whatever way you want by changing the definition of that function.

Or this would be much easier:

```
showQueue :: Show a => Queue a -> String
showQueue (Q xs) = show xs
```

Also don't use `deriving`, If you are going to create instance of it. Or else it will throw a compile error.

Comment: Thank you very much ! But what does concat $ intersperse means in this context ?

Comment: `intersperse` will put "," between the list and `concat` will concatenate them to a `String`